# Remove duplicates rows but change value on certain column if condition is met

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

So I have a .csv file with thousands of rows that have duplicates area names in column A and "Completed" values on column B (which can be "Completed" or "In Progress" in the same area).

| Area | Completed |
| --- | --- |
| Chicago | In Progress |
| Chicago | Completed |
| Chicago | In Progress |
| Chicago | In Progress |
| San Francisco | Completed |
| San Francisco | Completed |
| San Francisco | Completed |
| San Francisco | Completed |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |

I need to make it so that the end product is the following

| Area | Completed |
| --- | --- |
| Chicago | Particularly Completed |
| San Francisco | Completed |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |

The idea is to remove the duplicate area values and have the column B be determined by the original values with the following methodology:

- if all of the values in an area are "Completed" then column B is Completed
- if all of the values in an area are "In Progress" then column B is "In Progress"
- if one area contains values "In Progress" and "Completed" then the column B is Particularly Completed

So far I've thought about using a python script for this, but want to know if doing this would be possible with just excel as well?

Comment: You can do it with excel formula. What is your excel version?

Comment: I am using version 2205 @Harun24hr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula I have used in `D2` cell

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A13)
```

Then in `E2` cell

```
=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13=D2)))>1,"Particularly Complete",UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13=D2)))
```

and drag down till need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A correct answer has already been indicated. Anyway, if one doesn't have the `UNIQUE` or the `FILTER` function, here is another solution:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Area | Completed |  |  |  |
| Chicago | In Progress | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",A2) | =IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C:C)/(C:C<>""),ROW(D2)-ROW($D$2)+1)),"") | =IF(D2="","",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,D2)=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"Completed"),"Completed",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,D2)=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"In Progress"),"In Progress",IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"Completed")>0,COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"In Progress")>0),"Particularly Completed","Unpredicted Outcome")))) |
| Chicago | Completed |  |  |  |
| Chicago | In Progress |  |  |  |
| Chicago | In Progress |  |  |  |
| San Francisco | Completed |  |  |  |
| San Francisco | Completed |  |  |  |
| San Francisco | Completed |  |  |  |
| San Francisco | Completed |  |  |  |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |  |  |  |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |  |  |  |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |  |  |  |
| Los Angeles | In Progress |  |  |  |

Formulas in column C, D and E has to be dragged down. Column C filters the Area list leaving only unique areas. Column D sort the list of unique areas of column C. Column E gives the actual response. Once could easily obtain a list of unique areas with little work (which could be better if the list is really long), so the "real deal" is just the formula in column E which work on said list.

Answer (score 0):

Or create a Pivot Table on the original data which will look like:
[image]

Then in D3 apply your logic `=IF(B3>0,IF(C3=0,"Completed","Partially Completed"),"In Progress")`
[image]

You can then easily add more columns showing proportion of subdistricts completed, or number of districts with only one subdistrict to complete or suchlike.